# $.cookie working only inside jquery events and not inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, cookies

$.cookie function is working fine when I am trying to use it inside $(document).ready() but when I am trying to use the same logic inside a custom javascript method it shows "$.cookie is not a function" in the web console. I have installed and included the plugin inside my code. 
Please help! :)

Comment: Ok. So where are you putting it?  ARe you including the plugin script in your page?

Comment: @S.Khatter Always Post Relevant Code

Answer (score 1):

### "$.cookie is not a function" this is because 3 reasons

Just check

1. jquery plugin included ?.
2. jquery cookie plugin included ?.
3. Above order is maintained ?.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery `<script src=` is in a different scope in the first `$(document).ready()` call compared to the second.  Not much else we can say since we can't see your code.